# Why can't Unix users renice downwards?

Tags: unix, root, priority

I know that non-root users can renice a process **up**, but not renice a process priority *down*.

```
$ nice yes >/dev/null & p=$!
$ renice 15 -p $p 
8414: old priority 10, new priority 15
$ renice 12 -p $p
renice: 8414: setpriority: Permission denied
$ kill $p
```

I understand that as a non-root user I should not have the ability to (re)nice a process into negative nice territory, or that root may have started a process on my behalf at a higher nice level.

The question is **for what logical reason can a non-root user *not* renice their own processed downward**, even if just no further down to the original priority in which it was instatiated?

Answer (score 7):

If root users are able to reprioritize another user's process because it's using too much resources, a user should not be able to circumvent that and change it back.

Comment: Should we not consider nice values [-20,-1] to be system priorities vs. the user 'space' [0,19] I get what you're saying but I'm of the recent persuasion that user processes should be able to re-prioritize themselves or their children...at least from a base priority set by root?

Comment: Yes but the root user may realize the base priority was too high and reprioritize all of a certain users processes ( `renice -u user...` ). I've seen my school's sysadmin do something similar to our processes when he was running batch jobs so it would finish faster.

Answer (score 4):

`renice` modifies program niceness - higher number means lower priority.

I guess the reason is that the starting niceness isn't probably not remembered - only the current niceness value. So there's no good way of determining if a user can renice a program to higher priority. (This is a guess... Maybe someone can verify it? )

Answer (score 3):

Because then programs would have an incentive to prioritize themselves at the expense of the entire system.

Comment: Not necessarily.  For instance, user renice could not drop below 0.

Comment: ...which would still give the process a higher priority than all those other processes running at 20.